# Getting handle of child window in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I want to get handle of child window, but cannot.
I want to automatically insert text in an Edit control.
Here is what I have:

```
//global var

int id=0;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
  id = GetDlgCtrlID(hwnd);
  HWND hwnd_Child;
  hwnd_Child = GetDlgItem(hwnd, id);
   SendMessage(hwnd_Child, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"mYtexttttt");
  /* other code */
  // id is always 0, why ?
  // return FALSE; // stop enumerating
  return TRUE; // continue enumeration
}

void MyFunction ()
{
    HWND hwnd_Parent;

    hwnd_Parent = FindWindow(NULL,"MyTitle"); if(! hwnd)return;

    EnumChildWindows(hWnd ,(WNDENUMPROC)EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
}
```

In WinSpy++, the control IDs of all the components are 000000000. Is it possible that the control ID isn't defined?

How do I find the child handle of some specific (edit box) component if I have the handle of the main window, and the control ID is not defined?

*Also, main window is a game application which runs with DirectX, I think.*
 I want to automatically insert text in a Edit control.

Comment: Sometimes IDs are not defined, but your code looks all wrong anyway. How are you trying to identify the child window? How are you going to say which one you want?

Comment: for first I'm testing, I try to SendMessage to all handlers found by EnumChildWindows .... but this not helping, I want to automatically to insert text in a Edit control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If WinSpy tells you that the control IDs are 0 then getting a 0 back from GetDlgCtrlID() is of course the expected outcome.  You'll have to do something else, like counting down the number of EnumWindowsProc() calls and/or calling GetClassName() so you can see it is an edit control.  Or GetWindowRect() to go by position.

Comment: Okay...I did what you said, I used GetClassName() and all components have "Edit" class name, and callback function I sendmessage to all  SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"mYtexttttt");

Answer (score 2):

In your callback method, please do the following:

```
// get the window text
GetWindowText(hWnd, (LPTSTR)windowText, MAX_PATH);

// get the window info
WINDOWINFO objWinInfo;
GetWindowInfo(hWnd, &objWinInfo)
```

The above should help you get the child windows.

Also you can do `FindWindowEx` to the get the child windows.

Comment: please read my post , I updated it..... all I want is to find handle of Edit control and automatically insert text in box... but I'm not able to do this

Answer (score 1):

Control ids are one convenient way to identify child windows; but not the only way. So it is quite possible that control id will be set to arbitrary (or zero) values (in which case the parent window just refers to them directly by their handles.

From your point of view if no control ids exist you must reference them by the position in the tab sequence which should be constant and can be iterated through.

Comment: In callback function I send message to all Edit components , code: SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"mYtexttttt"); 
But this not work, why ?

Comment: In callback function I send message to all Edit components , code: SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"mYtexttttt"); But this not work, why ?

Comment: Not sure that you CAN do this from an external process/thread - seems like a serious security risk to me.